# How to open a form only if Login information is correct?

Tags: c#, forms

I apologize if my title is confusing as I wasn't sure of the best way to word my question.

Basically what I am trying to do is to open a form from another form but only if the correct login information is inputted into the text boxes. If incorrect credentials are inputted then the form isn't displayed.

When attempting this it caused an error in the else statement saying it is an 'invalid expression' due to me wanting to show the user_menu screen in the line above.

Does anyone know how I can make the form open only when the login information is correct?

Below is the code for the 'Login button'.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("F:\\Top-up Year 1\\OOD\\SRS_System3\\SRS_System\\LogIn.txt");
            username = sr.ReadLine();
            password = sr.ReadLine();
            User_menu usermenu = new User_menu();
            sr.Close();


            if (username == textBox1.Text && password == textBox2.Text)
                MessageBox.Show("You are now successfully logged in!", "Success!");
                usermenu.Show();    

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect!", "Error!");
        }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("The user does not exist!", "Error!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need curly braces in your `if` statement:

```
if (username == textBox1.Text && password == textBox2.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You are now successfully logged in!", "Success!");
    usermenu.Show(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate the quick answer too! :)